# Parse error when using case expression inside guards haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, syntax-error, case

I am new to Haskell and I am having issues with syntax. What I want to do is given data and a tree of this datatype, find the path to the corresponding node in the tree. I believe my logic for the function is correct but I am not sure how to make it valid Haskell. I have tried changing tabs to spaces.

```
-- | Binary trees with nodes labeled by values of an arbitrary type.
data Tree a
   = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
   | End
  deriving (Eq,Show)

-- | One step in a path, indicating whether to follow the left subtree (L)
--   or the right subtree (R).
data Step = L | R
  deriving (Eq,Show)

-- | A path is a sequence of steps. Each node in a binary tree can be
--   identified by a path, indicating how to move down the tree starting
--   from the root.
type Path = [Step]
pathTo :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe Path
pathTo a End = Nothing
pathTo a (Node b l r)
    | a == b = Just []
    | case (pathTo a l) of
                Just p  -> Just [L:p]
                Nothing -> case (pathTo a r) of
                                    Just p  -> Just [R:p]
                                    Nothing -> Nothing
```

This is the error:

```
  parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Comment: this does not look like a guard, you need `otherwise = ...`

Comment: This doesn't look like a parse error, your type is wrong.

Comment: Your edit made the answer unrelated to the question. If you have a follow-up question, post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that this does not look like a guard: a guard is an expression with type `Bool`, this determines if the guard "fires" or not. Here this is likely `otherwise:

```
pathTo :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe Path
pathTo a End = Nothing
pathTo a (Node b l r)
    | a == b = Just []
    | otherwise = case (pathTo a l) of
                Just p  -> Just (L:p)
                Nothing -> case (pathTo a r) of
                                    Just p  -> Just (R:p)
                                    Nothing -> Nothing
```

This also revealed some extra mistakes: `Just [L:p]` is a `Maybe [[Step]]`, you likely wanted to use `Just (L:p)`, the same applies for `Just [R:p]`.

You furthermore do not need to use nested `case`s, you can work with the [**`Alternative`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--124--62-) typeclass:

```
import Control.Applicative((<|>))

pathTo :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe Path
pathTo a End = Nothing
pathTo a (Node b l r)
    | a == b = Just []
    | otherwise = ((L:) <$> pathTo a l) <|> ((R:) <$> pathTo a r)
```

Here `x <|> y` will take `x` if it is a `Just …`, and `y` otherwise. We use `(L:) <$> …` to prepend the list wrapped in the `Just` data constructor, or return `Nothing` in case `…` is `Nothing`.